# How to store deployment code for microservices?

Tags: deployment, architecture, microservices, devops

I have a number of C# microservices in different repositories. All of these need OpenShift configuration code, including variables, config maps, services description, secrets, etc. I see following variants of storing deployment configs:

1. Together with source code
2. Separate from source code, each service config in separate repo
3. Separate from source code, all services configs in one repo

There are number of articles about "monorepo vs polyrepo", yet the deployment part is always missing. What are the guidelines here and advantages/disadvantages to each approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you my two cents on this, since I went through a similar problem.

#### 1. Together with source-code

This is not really a good idea since often the `secrets`, `config-maps` and so on, are different between environments, so you would have to manage environments in each microservice's repository, which then could bring many other problems, like changing settings by mistake in the wrong environment.

Furthermore, many other problems arise when dealing with shared secrets, because you would have to know that a secret X exists in the cluster.

#### 2. One infrastructure repo per microservice

With this approach you separate the code from the infrastructure, however it is hard to have a high view of the whole application, i.e., if you have 10 microservices you would have ten different 10 repositories and you would have to know that each one of them exist and is needed to run the system.

#### 3. All infrastructure code in one repository

This approach allows you to view all your dependencies and configuration in one place, i.e., your application as a whole. The only issue here is that you might need different permissions to access different environments, e.g., you might want everyone to be able to change infrastructure configurations in the `test` environment but only a few authorized people in the `production` environment.

#### 4. One repo per environment

Finally, the best alternative in my opinion is to have a repository for each environment, e.g., you can have a different repository for `production`, `pre-production`, `test` environments. It brings all the advantages of the previous approach with the addition that now it is much easier to control who can change configurations in each environment.

Furthermore, it also allows you to evolve the configurations in a total independent way, e.g., when you develop new functionality, you only need to change the `test` environment of your application, without the risk of changing something in production.

Comment: "All infrastructure code in one repository" - I'd add another issue: the separate deployment of updated services. What if I have 100 services and one got updated. Do I have to redeploy all of them?

Comment: @AlexanderKozachenko No, we should have our CI/CD pipelines aware of this possibility and only trigger the deployment on the updated services.

Comment: that's the tricky part, not sure how to implement it in gitlab